# getting the index of the max value in list and returning the values in subsequent lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, max

I have a df

```
review                          review_id   word_count
['abc def', 'ghi']              [1, 2]      [2, 1]
['jkl mno pqr', 'stu', 'vwx']   [3, 4, 5]   [3, 1, 1]
```

For each row in the df, I would like to create new columns for review and review_id whereby there will only consist of the review/review_id with the maximum word count.
Thus, the output should look something like this.

```
review         review_id
abc def        1      
jkl mno pqr    3
```

I can only think of getting the index of the max value in word_count. Any sugeestions will be welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: Is the word_count sorted in descending order ?  Can you have multiple reviews that have maximum counts and you want all of them to be included in you answer ?

Comment: @Manish the word_count is not sorted in descending order. Yes i can have multiple reviews that have the SAME number of word count but I only want one of it to be included in my answer. I am ok with any of it, probably just the lower review_id if possible. Is that a solution for that?

Comment: That's totally fine. You have a nice answer already by: jezrael. So I shall pass here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with compare maximal values per groups (from rows) and select rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) if need all maximal values:

```
df = df.explode(['review','review_id','word_count'])
#for oldier pandas versions
#df = df.apply(lambda x: x.explode())

df2 = df[df['word_count'].eq(df.groupby(level=0)['word_count'].transform('max'))]
print (df2)
        review review_id word_count
0      abc def         1          2
1  jkl mno pqr         3          3
```

EDIT: First create unique MultiIndex:

```
df = (df.apply(lambda x: x.explode())
        .assign(new=lambda x: range(len(x)))
        .set_index('new', append=True))
print (df)
            review review_id word_count
  new                                  
0 0        abc def         1          2
  1            ghi         2          1
1 2    jkl mno pqr         3          3
  3            stu         4          1
  4            vwx         5          1
```

Then get indices for maximal `word_count` per first level of MultiIndex (groups represent rows) by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and select them by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df['word_count'] = df['word_count'].astype(int)

df2 = df.loc[df.groupby(level=0)['word_count'].idxmax()].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df2)
        review review_id  word_count
0      abc def         1           2
1  jkl mno pqr         3           3
```

Comment: how can i amend the code such that if there are more than one review with the same number of max word count, it would only return the one with lowest review_id?

Comment: I have this error when i ran the second code: TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype

then I added in .astype('int') before .idxmax and got this error: AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'astype'

Comment: @odebear - add `df['word_count'] = df['word_count'].astype(int)`, answer was edited.

Answer (score 1):

For efficiency, you can use a list comprehension and the DataFrame constructor. This will be at least one order of magnitude faster than using `explode`:

```
import numpy as np
df2 = pd.DataFrame([(a[(m:=np.argmax(x))], b[m]) for a,b,x in
                    zip(df['review'], df['review_id'], df['word_count'])],
                   index=df.index, columns=['review', 'review_id']
                   )
print(df2)
```

output:

```
        review  review_id
0      abc def          1
1  jkl mno pqr          3
```

If you want all columns:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([(a[(m:=np.argmax(x))], b[m], x[m]) for a,b,x in
                    zip(df['review'], df['review_id'], df['word_count'])],
                   index=df.index, columns=df.columns
                   )
```

output:

```
        review  review_id  word_count
0      abc def          1           2
1  jkl mno pqr          3           3
```

##### timing

on 20k rows

```
# list comprehension
50.2 ms ± 1.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# explode + groupby
1.22 s ± 10 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```